# Laravel button does not link to route

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>{{ $id->title }}</h1>

            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($id->notes as $note)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        {{ $note->body }}
                        <span class="pull-right">
                                <button href="/notes/{{ $note->id }}/edit" type="button" class="label label-default pull-xs-right">Edit</button>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <hr>
            <h3>Add a New Note</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="post" action="/cards/{{ $id->id }}/notes">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

The button in the foreach loop has the correct link, /note/id/edit. I can type that into chrome and go to the edit page.  However, the button does not head there.  I just see the click animation.  Why would this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button element does not have the `href` attribute so you can either wrap it in a link tag like this. and this is the easiest way

```
<a href="{{"/notes/". $note->id. "/edit"}}" >
<button type="button" class="label label-default pull-xs-right">Edit</button
></a>
```

or you can wrap it in a form element and set the action attribute to your desired link like this.

```
<Form method="get" action="{{"/notes/". $note->id. "/edit"}}">
<button type="submit" class="label label-default pull-xs-right">Edit</button>
</Form>
```

the 3rd way is to use javascript and onclick listener.

Comment: I used the second suggestion, but had to change the button type to 'submit'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use  `<a></a>` tag, instead of `button`, and set `type="button"`

```
 <a href="{{ route('change.anything') }}" type="button"> Check Any </a>
```